Unpack the first N-1 elements of a parameter pack
template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
{
    // N = sizeof...(args)   
    // need args[0], args[1] ..., args[N-2] as tuple and/or forward them
}

I have C++20 at my disposal. What is a short way of getting all but the last element of a pack as a tuple?
Or is there way without a tuple?
I need to forward all but the last element.

Is there any way to access everything except the last template parameter?

@user12002570 I don't think your provided link matches this question. It doesn't even contain how to forward everything but the last parameter, but rather how to build a tuple type that contains all but the last. It also deals with template arguments (the values are in the template parameters), and not in the function arguments.

@ABu, agreed. That question also relates specifically to c++11, while this relates to c++20. This question is definitely solvable with some ugly recursion, but (like the questioner here) I'm also curious if there's now a nicer way to do this in c++20.

@Elliott no recursion needed. I got something like this although I'm not fully sure about whether the forwarding is done right: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f6ed8aefd2f6b30

@ABu: thank you for this example. Would you mind creating a full answer here?

@Juergen The question is closed so that's not possible. Anyway, I'm not fully sure if the implementation is 100% right, specifically, I'm not sure if the std::move of the tuple is needed. I think it's but maybe it's not.

Following ABu's comment, it is even possible to define a more generic slice_forward method that takes the arguments of indexes in a given range [from:to[, see here https://godbolt.org/z/xsooqGP3G
